# how to create filter by year for table sort by some row table with laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-blade

hello i'm new at laravel but i had some issue with change some table view of job recap,and want to sort by some attribute in a table DB with some script reference like this

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center mb-2">
               <label class="mb-0 mr-2">Tahun Periode</label>
                     <select name="year" id="year" class="form-control" style="max-width:200px">
                           @for ($i = 2021; $i <= date('Y')+1; $i++)
                               <option value="{{$i}}">{{$i}}</option>
                           @endfor
                     </select>
               <div style="max-width:100px">
               </div>
</div>
```

```
const date = new Date();
            var fYear = date.getFullYear();
            $('#year').change(function () {
                fYear= $('#year').val();
                tbl.draw();
            });

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
                var month = parseInt($('#mois').val(), 10);
                var year = fYear;
                if(level == 'superadmin'){
                    var date = data[4].split('-');
                }else{
                    var date = data[3].split('-');
                }
                if ((isNaN(year)) ||
                    (year == date[2])
                ) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
                }
            );
```

so... can i get some advice to change it by (if i need to change the model or change at that file) ?

Comment: You want to sort your result by Year?

Comment: yup, but sort link with my job year from DB